# Unable to play 360 degrees video just like Youtube Player App

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am exploring the Youtube Player API and I would like to play the 360 degrees video just like it is playable in YouTube app. The API is not letting me play just like in the app - Video looks distorted.

I am using sample code from the below given link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

For 360 degrees video testing purpose, I replaced the video ID. Below is the snippet of file - StandalonePlayerDemoActivity.java

```
private static final String VIDEO_ID = "AHrR6YP84ds";
```

Initially, When I executed the sample code, it worked just like the YouTube app but then it is now playing just like normal video which is distorted.

Please suggest a way to resolve.

TIA.